# WebStorm git add --patch utilization

Tags: git, webstorm

Does anyone know if WebStorm 11 offers the functionality `git add --patch` and if so how to utilize it in WebStorm 11 ?

I've found this thing on JetBrains website: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/creating-patches.html

Although I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for since I never used `git add --patch` before, and as described in the page it creates a patch file. Now I don't know if this patch file is what I'm referring to or is it just a feature the idea gives to do something completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not about creating patches, it's about Git interactive mode support; see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add for more information. This feature is not currently supported by WebStorm. Please follow [IDEA-63201](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63201) for updates